# Problems Deserialising a nested object array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here are my models:

```
public class Order
{
    public IEnumerable<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class LineItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("product_id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("variation_id")]
    public int VariationId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("tax_class")]
    public string TaxClass { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("subtotal")]
    public string Subtotal { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("subtotal_tax")]
    public string SubtotalTax { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("total")]
    public string Total { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("total_tax")]
    public string TotalTax { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("taxes")]
    public List<object> Taxes { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("meta_data")]
    public List<MetaData> MetaData { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("sku")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("parent_name")]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the HttpRequest property contains an array of line items:

```
[
    {
    "id":7928,
    "parent_id":0,
    "status":"on-hold",
    "currency":"GBP",
    "version":"5.7.1",
    "prices_include_tax":true,
    "date_created":"2021-10-04T00:26:22",
    "date_modified":"2021-10-04T00:26:22",
    "discount_total":"0.00",
    "discount_tax":"0.00",
    "shipping_total":"0.00",
    "shipping_tax":"0.00",
    "cart_tax":"0.00",
    "total":"2.50",
    "total_tax":"0.00",
    "customer_id":3,
    "order_key":"redacted",
    "billing":{
       "first_name":"redacted",
       "last_name":"redacted",
       "company":"",
       "address_1":"redacted",
       "address_2":"redacted",
       "city":"redacted",
       "state":"redacted",
       "postcode":"redacted",
       "country":"GB",
       "email":"redacted",
       "phone":"redacted"
    },
    "shipping":{
        "first_name":"redacted",
        "last_name":"redacted",
        "company":"",
        "address_1":"redacted",
        "address_2":"redacted Lane",
        "city":"redacted",
        "state":"redacted",
        "postcode":"redacted",
        "country":"GB",
        "phone":""
     },
     "payment_method":"bacs",
     "payment_method_title":"Direct bank transfer",
     "transaction_id":"",
     "customer_ip_address":"redacted",
     "customer_user_agent":"redacted",
     "created_via":"redacted",
     "customer_note":"",
     "date_completed":null,
     "date_paid":null,
     "cart_hash":"redacted",
     "number":"redacted",
     "meta_data":[
        {
           "id":190011,
           "key":"redacted",
           "value":"no"
        },
        {
           "id":190012,
           "key":"redacted",
           "value":"yes"
        },
        {
           "id":190016,
           "key":"_new_order_email_sent",
           "value":"true"
        },
        {
           "id":190017,
           "key":"_thankyou_action_done",
           "value":"1"
        }
     ],
     "line_items":[
        {
           "id":5287,
           "name":"John Guest 3\/8 to 1\/4 Fitting PI0112f4S",
           "product_id":5699,
           "variation_id":0,
           "quantity":1,
           "tax_class":"",
           "subtotal":"2.50",
           "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
           "total":"2.50",
           "total_tax":"0.00",
           "taxes":[
              
           ],
           "meta_data":[
              {
                 "id":48648,
                 "key":"_WCPA_order_meta_data",
                 "value":"",
                 "display_key":"_WCPA_order_meta_data",
                 "display_value":""
              }
           ],
           "sku":"",
           "price":2.5,
           "parent_name":null
        }
     ],
     "tax_lines":[
        
     ],
     "shipping_lines":[
        {
           "id":5288,
           "method_title":"Collect from store",
           "method_id":"local_pickup",
           "instance_id":"13",
           "total":"0.00",
           "total_tax":"0.00",
           "taxes":[
              
           ],
           "meta_data":[
              {
                 "id":48647,
                 "key":"Items",
                 "value":"John Guest 3\/8 to 1\/4 Fitting PI0112f4S &times; 1",
                 "display_key":"Items",
                 "display_value":"John Guest 3\/8 to 1\/4 Fitting PI0112f4S &times; 1"
              }
           ]
        }
     ],
     "fee_lines":[
        
     ],
     "coupon_lines":[
        
     ],
     "refunds":[
        
     ],
     "date_created_gmt":"2021-10-03T23:26:22",
     "date_modified_gmt":"2021-10-03T23:26:22",
     "date_completed_gmt":null,
     "date_paid_gmt":null,
     "currency_symbol":"\u00a3",
     "_links":{
        "self":[
           {
              "href":"redacted"
           }
        ],
        "collection":[
           {
              "href":"redacted"
           }
        ],
        "customer":[
           {
              "href":"redacted"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
]
```

I am wondering why when this is deserialized using

```
public class WooCommerceOrders
    {
        private HttpRequestService _httpRequestService;
        private string _url;

        public WooCommerceOrders()
        {
            _httpRequestService = new HttpRequestService();
            _url = "https://kegthat.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders";
        }

        public List<Order> GetOrdersJson()
        {
            var result = _httpRequestService.CallApi(_url).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return _httpRequestService.DeserializeApiResponseJson<List<Order>>(result.Result);
        }
    }
```

The json for line items returns

```
"lineItems": null,
```

however some fields such as shipping return

```
"shipping": {
"firstName": null,
"lastName": null,
"company": "",
"address1": null,
"address2": null,
"city": "redacting city",
"state": "Cheshire",
"postcode": "redacting postcode",
"country": "GB",
"phone": ""
},
```

This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content
This wont let me add too much more code than content

Why can I not return line items?

Comment: you need to post the whole json, if you want to get help

Comment: One min will post soon

Comment: @Ben you are expecting list of orders, where is it coming from? I see orders class is list of items. but I don't see list of orders

Comment: Hi has my updated json provided helped at all? If not can you clarify @jmag

Comment: There we go @Serge

Comment: What deserializer are you using (`System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json` are the two most common). `JsonPropertyName` attribute is `System.Text.Json` specific,  while `JsonProperty` is used by `Newtonsoft.Json`. Just a wild guess. Otherwise, you can try commenting out all properties in `LineItem` class and seeing at what point the deserialization starts to fail. So start by just having the `Id` property uncommented, then also `ProductId`, etc.

Comment: @Ben Is the api passes a list of orders? Or just order( list of lineitems)?

Comment: Okay so don't worry about the api I am getting all the data from the api but I am losing some when deserialising var result = CallApi(_url).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var x = DeserializeApiResponseJson<List<Order>>(result.Result);
            return DeserializeApiResponseJson<List<Order>>(result.Result); at the first line I have everything then is lost when deserialising

Comment: @nbokmans I am doing this JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);

Comment: `JsonConvert` is Newtonsoft.Json. Can you try changing all your `JsonPropertyName` attributes to `JsonProperty`? The rest of the attribute is entirely the same.

Comment: @nbokmans unfortunately that has not solved the problem :(

Comment: @Ben what is lineitems? And line_items?  you said lineitems=null and line_items is in the data.

Comment: @Ben Also check if you should be DeserializeApiResponseJson<List<Order> or DeserializeApiResponseJson<Order>.

Comment: @jmag thank you you have saved me it was simply a silly mistake of mine!!! Cheers

Comment: @Ben you are most welcome I was hinting on it from the start. Let me write the answer for future references other's can use.

Comment: @Ben thank you for accepting my answer, though it was short lived. Please accept the answer that actually helped you next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.....

 public List<Order> GetOrdersJson()
{
var result = _httpRequestService.CallApi(_url).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<Order>>(result.Result);
}
```

test to get line_items

```
var result= GetOrdersJson();
var lineItems=result[0].line_items;

[
  {
    "id": 5287,
    "name": "John Guest 3/8 to 1/4 Fitting PI0112f4S",
    "product_id": 5699,
    "variation_id": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "tax_class": "",
    "subtotal": "2.50",
    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
    "total": "2.50",
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "taxes": [],
    "meta_data": [
      {
        "id": 48648,
        "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
        "value": "",
        "display_key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
        "display_value": ""
      }
    ],
    "sku": "",
    "price": 2.5,
    "parent_name": null
  }
]
```

classes

```
public class Order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_modified { get; set; }
    public string discount_total { get; set; }
    public string discount_tax { get; set; }
    public string shipping_total { get; set; }
    public string shipping_tax { get; set; }
    public string cart_tax { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string order_key { get; set; }
    public Billing billing { get; set; }
    public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
    public string payment_method { get; set; }
    public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
    public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
    public string created_via { get; set; }
    public string customer_note { get; set; }
    public object date_completed { get; set; }
    public object date_paid { get; set; }
    public string cart_hash { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public List<MetaData> meta_data { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> line_items { get; set; }
    public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
    public List<ShippingLine> shipping_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> refunds { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created_gmt { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_modified_gmt { get; set; }
    public object date_completed_gmt { get; set; }
    public object date_paid_gmt { get; set; }
    public string currency_symbol { get; set; }
    public Links _links { get; set; }
}


public class Billing
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class Shipping
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string display_key { get; set; }
    public string display_value { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int product_id { get; set; }
    public int variation_id { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string tax_class { get; set; }
    public string subtotal { get; set; }
    public string subtotal_tax { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
    public List<MetaData> meta_data { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public object parent_name { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingLine
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string method_title { get; set; }
    public string method_id { get; set; }
    public string instance_id { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
    public List<MetaData> meta_data { get; set; }
}

public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public List<Self> self { get; set; }
    public List<Collection> collection { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` is not a valid type for the serializer. It doesn't define any concrete implementation of a collection for the serializer to parse the JSON into. Use `List<T>` when deserializing JSON arrays.

Comment: I tried the same with both List and IEnumerable, still does not work

Comment: You did not define a `JsonPropertyAttribute` for LineItems either to match on the `line_items` JSON property key. Have you added that property name mapping to the data contract?

Comment: Hi can you clarify and show an example of what you mean here? Cheers

Comment: In your `LineItem` class you have decorated the class properties with `JsonPropertyName` attributes, which instruct the serializer what the property name in JSON is expected to be if it's not a 1:1 match to the C# member name.

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks for this but I have sorted it thanks for the help. Yeah you were right :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you've marked the answer as what you did but your sample JSON shows an array of Order objects. If that's not the correct sample it would be helpful to provide the actual JSON contents.

Comment: @Andrew Is this why answer was not honored even if it was the solution. The request was to identify why deserialization was not working as he expected it would be. The JSON code was not the issue. The issue is trying was JSON Deserializer was receiving a List.  Please read the conversation until the end.

Comment: @jmag the JSON he provided was a list of Order objects. I see he marked a new answer as the solution, where previously your answer was (I believe incorrectly) marked as the solution. Serge's solution I can agree with.

Comment: @Andrew he did not changed his code. He just simply realized that he was passing a List to the JSONDeserializer. He accepted my answer because he was able to resolve the issue with it. That is the reason in the first place it was picked. Not because he given a some code. It was not picked incorrectly. He just simply accepted the answer that helped him resolve his issue. I can agree with that Serge's answer is correct but the user still can choose what actually identified the issue he was facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<Order> GetOrdersJson()
    {
        var result = _httpRequestService.CallApi(_url).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return _httpRequestService.DeserializeApiResponseJson<Order>(result.Result);
    }
```

Deserializing `List<Order>` which is not the Deserializer is expecting.
Try `return _httpRequestService.DeserializeApiResponseJson<Order>` instead